# how to get List Of User Defined Functions using OleDbSchemaGuid in c#?

Tags: function, defined

how to get List Of User Defined Functions using  OleDbSchemaGuid in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You use `OleDbSchemaGuid.Procedures` with the `GetOleDbSchemaTable` method.  The value of the restriction column in the resulting data set will be DB_PT_FUNCTION if the procedure returns a function.